# Header file reference error when compiling gdbserver

Tags: c, gdb, cross-compiling, gdbserver

My gdb source version is 9.2, the cross compiler is `arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc`, which has a gcc version of 7.3, and I'm running on wsl2 ubuntu22.04.
While compiling, I go to . /gdb/gdbserver,
then enter

```
./configure --target=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi --host=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi
```

to configure, followed by `make CC=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi` to compile. The following error occurs

```
CC cloexec.o
../../../../../gnulib/import/cloexec.c:24:10: fatal error: errno.h: No such file or directory
 #include <errno.h>
```

But the corresponding directory has the file

I tried adding the compiler option `-I`, but it didn't work.